# Javascript Get the children of an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the src of the image inside the a tag using javascript code.For that I used this code:

```js
function changestyle(cat) {

  var el = $(cat).find('.img_box').attr('id');

  console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="changestyle(this);" id="onc_2">
  this is the first anchor
  <div class="">hello</div> 
  <div class="img_box" id='gtrf'>
    <a href="" class="yyy" id='tttt'>
      <img src="images/arrows_list.png" class="c1"/>
      image1 to be changed
    </a>
  </div>
</a>
 <a href="#" onclick="changestyle(this);" id="onc_2">
  this is second anchor
    <div class="">hello</div> 
    <div class="img_box" id='gtrf'>
    <a href="" class="yyy" id='tttt'>
      <img src="images/arrows_list.png" class="c1"/>
     image2 to be changed with the onclick action
    </a>
   </div>
   </a>
```

But I always get undefined in the console. When I remove the `<a>` inside the clicked `<a>` it works. Is there any way to change the src of the image by clicking on the first `<a>`?

Comment: what is "cat" in javascript

Comment: @VivekGupta its the parameter passed in to the method, in this case a reference to the `a` element being clicked (you can see that in the markup)

Comment: It's invalid mark up with the nested link within a link. Remove the nested link, and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wdj1dvgu/

Comment: actually, anchor can't include anchor as a child. Generally, anchor shouldn't contain div, but if the div's display is inline element or anchor is block, this situation is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should check your general html-markup.

IDs have to be unique in its scope, see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) for furhter information. You should use classes instead.

```
<a href="#" id="onc_2" class="anchor">
  <div class="">lol</div> 
  <div class="img_box" id='gtrf'>
      <img src="your/src.png" class="c1"/>
  </div>
</a>
```

I removed the second `a`-tag here, according to the [w3c-specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

As you are using jQuery anyways, I would recommend to avoid inline-javascript.

```
$('.anchor').on('click', function(){

    var el = $(this).find('.img_box').attr('id');    
    var el = $(this).find('.img_box img').attr('src', new_src);   
    console.log(el);    

});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9d06v1s5/)

**Reference**

[.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="changestyle(this);" id="onc_2">mmm
<div class="">lol</div> 
<div class="img_box" id='gtrf'>
 <a href="" class="yyy" id='tttt'>
  <img src="images/arrows_list.png" id="target-image" class="c1"/>hhh
 </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var targetLink = document.getElementById('onc_2');
var targetImage = document.getElementById('target-image');

targetLink.addEventListener('click', function(){
  targetImage.src = yourNewImageSrc;
}, false);
```

Comment: but I don't have only one anchor, each anchor have the same onclick event and all have the same id and class. For this reason I used the function changestyle.

Comment: This will not reference the child-element of the clicked anchor.

Comment: I don't use the id, it's just for test. I just use the classes.